# Symfony 2 KNP Menu: add CSS class to link

Tags: php, css, symfony, knpmenubundle

I'm using the KnpMenuBundle for Symfony2 and I couldn't find a way to add a css class to the from the Menu generated links.

What I tried to set the class to the child attribute, but that will not be given to the link but to possible children menus (submenus).

```
    $menu->addChild('agb', array('uri' => '#'))
        ->setAttribute('divider_append', true)
        ->setChildenAttribute('class', 'childClass');
```

This will result into the following HTML

```
<li>
    <a href="#"> agb </a>
    <ul class="childClass">
        ....
    </ul>
</li>
```

But I need it like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="childClass"> agb </a>
    <ul>
        ....
    </ul>
</li>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$menu->addChild('agb', array('uri' => '#'))
    ->setAttribute('divider_append', true)
    ->setLinkAttribute('class', 'childClass');
```

easy as that :)